# MVC Endpoint URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, web-api-testing

I've recently started working with .NET MVC web API's and I'm confused by how the program is displaying info based on what the user types in for the URL.

For example, here's the endpoint in my controller:

```
  // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 
  public string Welcome(string name, int id = 1)
        {
            return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {name}, ID: {id}");
        }
```

and the pattern in my startup.cs file:

```
 pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

if I run the API and type this in for the URL: https://localhost:44370/HelloWorld/Welcome/12?name=Rick

The output is: Hello Rick, ID: 12

What i don't understand is how the program produces the output based on the parameters: Since i listed name as my first parameter, and the number 12 comes first in my URL after HelloWorld/ I don't understand how 12 isn't being stored in the variable name. I'm not sure how the program gets that output.

Comment: It doesn't use parameter order to bind data to variables, but it uses the parameter names to do the binding of parameters and values

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api

Comment: @armand I see. So the variables names in my url have to match what's in my program, but they don't have to be in any specific order. This makes a lot more sense. In my URL, why didn't i have to specify name=rick?

Comment: I do not understand your question?